# Weak convergence of random variable: it's in fact weak* convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

One definition of [weak convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) of a sequence of finite measures on a metric space $E$ is

> $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly on $E$ iff $\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu$ for all bounded continuous function $f.$

My question here is simple: in terms of functional analysis, the dual space of the space of continuous functions is the space of all finite measures, so what we state above is weak* convergence (rather than weak convergence) in terms of the definition for general Banach spaces.

So why are we not just calling this weak* convergence of measures?

Comment: It is weak* convergence ; unfortunately the terminology in Probability Theory conflicts with the one in FA. Another example: closed linear map in FA is not the same as  closed map in topology.

Comment: weak * convergence is a special case of a weak convergence, i.e. convergence wrt some family of functions. So they're not "lying", it is **a** weak convergence.

Comment: Another conflicting use of the term "weak" takes place in Operator Theory: a sequence $\{T_n\}_n$ of operators on a Hilbert space $H$ is said to converge weakly to some operator $T$ if $\langle T_n(x), y\rangle \to \langle T(x), y\rangle $, for all vectors $x$ and $y$ in $H$.  Nevertheless this is not the same as weak convergence in the space $\mathscr B(H)$ of all bounded operators on $H$.